# Inconsistencies in DateTime between local machine and Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-sql-database

I have an app hosted in an Azure Website.  When using the hosted application, the DateTimes are displayed and saved properly.  When I run the application locally, and pull the data from the Azure SQL database, I get very weird results.  Every datetime seems to be 6 hours off.

If I'm on my local box and I pull data from the server, all datetimes are displayed as actual+6 hours.

If I then, from local box, post something to Azure SQL, the time gets saved as actual-6hrs.

An example of the reads/writes I'm talking about:

Write:

```
        var chatMessage = new ChatMessage() {
                    DatePosted = DateTime.Now
                                        };
        db.ChatMessages.Add(chatMessage);
```

Read:

```
       // get chatMessage from db
       messageVm.DateIndicator = DateUtilities.GetFriendlyDate(chatMessage.DatePosted);
       // GetFriendlyDate is:
       public static string GetFriendlyDate(DateTime? postDate) {
        if (postDate == null) {
            return null;
        }
        string stringy = string.Empty;
        TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now.Subtract((DateTime) postDate);
        double days = diff.Days;
        double hours = diff.Hours + days * 24;
        double minutes = diff.Minutes + hours * 60;
        if (minutes <= 1) {
            return "Just Now";
        }
        // etc
        }
```

So in the above Read - if I'm running the app locally and accessing Azure SQL, content posted 5 hours ago is being displayed as posted "Just Now", and if I save a new message, the hosted application displays the time as 6 hours ago (when it should be "just now").

Splitting the logic (local) from the db (azure) is obviously the cause of this - but is this an indication that I'm not handling DateTimes properly?  If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's because your local Time Zone differs from the one used by azure.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - would an appropriate solution be to ALWAYS convert EVERY datetime to UTC in my app?

Comment: Yes, the simplest solution is to store datetimes in the database in UTC. You could then convert it to the user's timezone if it needs to be presented to the user.

Comment: ALWAYS. save in UTC. display in local.

Comment: @SB2055 Yes, that's the best way to go. Always store your datetime values in UTC.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - Thanks.  Would this just be a matter of setting the WRITE to `.ToUniversalTime`, and READ to `.ToLocalTime`?

Comment: @brendonparker - can I just convert all Datetime.Nows to UTC, always, since I never actually display the time?  (I just display 'x hours/days/weeks/etc ago')

Comment: @SB2055 Yes! If you only display how much time ago something happened you can always use UTC and don't care about local time at all.

Comment: I don't think you should always store in UTC. If the time displayed is a local time being stored it should stay that way. For example if I make an appointment at 4pm next week and save as UTC. The next day day -light savings time starts my appointment is still 4pm not 5pm which the UTC conversion will try and tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in a different time zone. Use `DateTime` in UTC, or better yet avoid all the oddities of that and use `DateTimeOffset`.

Unlike .NET's `DateTime` type, databases don't have a "Kind" that indicates if they're a local or UTC date. This makes them really easy to use inconsistently and not even realize it. `DateTimeOffset` stores an offset from UTC, so it does not have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `DateTime.UtcNow` rather than `DateTime.Now`